# Pandas mapping values in 2 dataframes and outer-join + aggregate values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, outer-join

Hello I have these 2 dataframes

```
df_1
title      URL  number         date
    a   /url-1       1   21-02-2020
    a   /url-1      10   20-02-2020
    a   /url-1      17   18-02-2020
    b   /url-2     100   21-02-2020
    b   /url-2     106   20-02-2020
```

```
df_2
   URL  number         date
/url-1       5   21-02-2020
/url-1      12   20-02-2020
/url-1      50   19-02-2020
/url-2      71   17-02-2020
/url-3       9   21-02-2020
/url-3      11   20-02-2020
```

So I need to perform these **Actions** to combine them into 1 dataframe:

1) Add new column call df_2["title"] to map df_2["URL"] values to values in df_1["title"]

2) Outer join both dataframes together

3) Aggregate df_1["number"] and df_2["number"] by "date" and sum them together

This is the result I want:

```
new_df
title      URL  number         date
    a   /url-1       6   21-02-2020
    a   /url-1      22   20-02-2020
    a   /url-1      50   19-02-2020
    a   /url-1      17   18-02-2020
    b   /url-2     100   21-02-2020
    b   /url-2     106   20-02-2020
    b   /url-2      71   17-02-2020
 null   /url-3       9   21-02-2020
 null   /url-3      11   20-02-2020
```

Things to take note:

A) I can't just outer join on "URL" and "date" as you can notice that in df_2;row 3 (19-02-2020) doesn't appear to have the same date in df_1 for "/url-1". The same issue applies to df_2;row 4 as well

B) I don't mind to skip Action 1 (as bolded above) if I can achieve what I want for new_df

Your help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), then new column is used for outer join, last `sum` columns:

```
df_2["title"] = df_2["URL"].map(df_1.drop_duplicates('URL').set_index('URL')["title"])

df = df_1.merge(df_2, on=['title','URL','date'], how='outer', suffixes=('','_'))
df['number'] = df['number'].add(df.pop('number_'), fill_value=0)
print (df)
  title     URL  number        date
0     a  /url-1     6.0  21-02-2020
1     a  /url-1    22.0  20-02-2020
2     a  /url-1    17.0  18-02-2020
3     b  /url-2   100.0  21-02-2020
4     b  /url-2   106.0  20-02-2020
5     a  /url-1    50.0  19-02-2020
6     b  /url-2    71.0  17-02-2020
7   NaN  /url-3     9.0  21-02-2020
8   NaN  /url-3    11.0  20-02-2020
```

Last if necessary aggregate `sum` - because missing values is necesary replace values by some non missing value:

```
df = (df.fillna('tmp')
         .groupby(['URL', 'date', 'title'], as_index=False)['number']
         .sum()
         .replace({'tmp':np.nan})
         .reindex(df.columns, axis=1))
```

Comment: just back to regularly answer python pandas question on SO after 2 years, you are still so fast with all the answers... :D

Comment: @PhungDuyPhong - hmmm, it depends.

Answer (score 1):

Add title to df2, then append, then group by:

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1.loc[:, ['title', 'URL']].drop_duplicates(), on='URL', how='left')

df = df1.append(df2)

# group by auto exclude NaN value, so fillna with placeholder first
df.fillna('null').groupby(['URL', 'date', 'title']).sum().reset_index()
```